# is there a way to fade image cards where they interact with surfaces

Tags: geometry-nodes, image, shader-nodes, simulation-nodes

I have a geo nodes explosion sim with image planes instanced to points  i want to fade the images where it collides with surfaces not just a plane but any surface

[image]

Comment: Hello ! Should be doable in the shader with an ambient occlusion node and a noise texture. Make sure the flame cards do not cause ambient occlusion themselves

Comment: Oh yeah that can be a solution but i want a bit more elegant way of doing that

Comment: Hmm, how is this not elegant ? It's litteraly three or four nodes to add to your shader tree

Comment: i experimented with the occlusion node a bit and it works quite perfectly but just a bit noisy  i am using eevee   anyway i think i got the solution thanks :D !